# Join and Insert characters in numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy array as follows.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
arr2 = np.array([-14, -24, -33, -41, -51, -61, -71])

arr1 = np.array_str(arr1)
arr2 = np.array_str(arr2)
```

I want to join the first with second and insert some static characters in between such that the final array looks like this below. Any suggestion how to do that?

```
res=[-14(0dBm), -24(10dBm), -33(20dBm), -41(30dBm), -51(40dBm), -61(50dBm), -71(60dBm)]
```

Comment: please provide valid objects, your current input is ambiguous (and invalid)

Comment: what else is needed. The values of the two arrays are strings.

Comment: if you copy paste your code, this will give a syntax error, also those are list not arrays. Sure I could guess what you want but please make the effort of providing a clean input in your question. What is needed is a code that gives the exact same object as you have

Comment: @mozway changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution:

```py
# Generate inputs
a = np.array("0 10 20 30 40 50 60".split(' '))
b = np.array("-14 -24 -33 -41 -51 -61 -71".split(' '))

# Generate resulting array
c = [f'{bi}({ai}dBm)' for (ai, bi) in zip(a,b)]
#> c = ['-14(0dBm)', '-24(10dBm)', '-33(20dBm)', '-41(30dBm)', ...
#>      '-51(40dBm)', '-61(50dBm)', '-71(60dBm)']
```

Alternatively, you can get it as a single string:

```py
c = ', '.join([f'{bi}({ai}dBm)' for (ai, bi) in zip(a,b)])
#> c = '-14(0dBm), -24(10dBm), -33(20dBm), -41(30dBm), -51(40dBm), -61(50dBm), -71(60dBm)'
```

#### EDIT

For the updated inputs in the question (they're a bit weird!), you can do just this:

```py
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]).array_str(arr1)
arr2 = np.array([-14, -24, -33, -41, -51, -61, -71]).array_str(arr2)

# Convert to a standard str array
to_arr = lambda arr: np.array(arr[1:-1].strip().split(' '))
a = to_arr(arr1)
b = to_arr(arr2)

# Generate resulting array in a single string
c = ', '.join([f'{bi}({ai}dBm)' for (ai, bi) in zip(a,b)]))
```

Comment: not working. ques is updated.

Comment: Aaah, you have a single string with the entire array. Weird, but OK. I'll modify it. Done!

Comment: Is it ok now? BTW you have a weird way of dealing with numpy string arrays. Your arrays have one single element instead of multiple (arr1[0] is the entire string).

Comment: sorry i missed the (,) in the resultant array..all these are seperated by (,)

Comment: Then just add a comma in the string before the `join` (editing the answer again)

Comment: May I ask why do you use a numpy array with a single element? Are you reading it from a file or another string?